# Make only two decimal after point (Angular)

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I have a directive for text input, that replaces text symbols and allows to type decimal numbers only.

Here is code for this directive

```
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HostListener, Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    exportAs: 'decimal-number-directive',
    selector: 'decimal-number-directive, [decimal-number-directive]'
})
export class DecimalNumberDirective {
    private el: NgControl;
    constructor(ngControl: NgControl) {
        this.el = ngControl;
    }
    // Listen for the input event to also handle copy and paste.
    @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
    onInput(value: string) {
        // Use NgControl patchValue to prevent the issue on validation
        this.el.control.patchValue(value.replace(/[^0-9].[^0-9]/, ''));
    }
}
```

Now I can write n - number decimal symbols. I need only two. How I can do this?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us the full range of allowed inputs?

Comment: Try specifying a quantifier like this: `/[0-9]+.[0-9]{0,2}/`

Comment: You use a negated character class `[^` which matches not a digit. Try `[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to show decimal places and not allow symbols I need to write directive like this

```
    import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HostListener, Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    exportAs: 'decimal-number-directive',
    selector: 'decimal-number-directive, [decimal-number-directive]',
})
export class DecimalNumberDirective {
    private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/g);
    private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-'];
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        console.log(this.el.nativeElement.value);
        // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
        if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
            return;
        }
        let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
        let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
        if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The pattern that you use also matches an empty string, a single dot or only a number. See https://regex101.com/r/rj4G4X/1. I have updated my answer with an example using [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) as well and left the example using [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern `[^0-9].[^0-9]` you are replacing 3 characters with an empty string. You match not a digit, any char except a newline using a dot and again not a digit using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^`

If you want to remove all chars except digits and dots you are still not sure if the format is correct because `...` could then also be valid.

Instead of replace, try matching a value with 2 decimals after the dot.

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$
```

If you would allow  starting with a dot, you could use a `*` instead of `+`:

```
^[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}$
```

Example using [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```js
let pattern = /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$/;
["2.22", "....", "1", "3.299"].forEach(s => console.log(s + ": " + pattern.test(s)));
```

Or using [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
let pattern = /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$/;
["2.22", "....", "1", "3.299"].forEach(s => {
  let res = s.match(pattern);
  console.log((null === res ? "No match: " : "Match: ") + s)
});
```

Comment: yeah. but not `{2}`, I need `{3}`
And if I will write 22.34 it's ok, if 22.343 it will delete whole value. I don't want this

Comment: @EugeneSukh You could try matching it instead of removing, because if you remove all except digits and dots then `.....` would also be valid.

Comment: your regex not replacing text symbols

Comment: In this case instead of using replace you could use test to test if the format is digit with 2 decimals.

Comment: I think Typescript don't have this stuff

Comment: @EugeneSukh you could also use the javascript `test` method instead of the `match`. In your pattern everything is optional and will also match an empty string or a single dot. You could use one of the patterns in my answer instead.